# How to display all values if no value passed to parameter in crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Crystal Report containing a parameter field. The parameter field works perfectly as long as I pas values to it. But what i want to do is that I want to display all values when no parameter is passed. When I pass no parameter a dialog box appears telling me to select the values I want to pass to the parameter. To work this out I tried to copy all the values I use pass to the parameter and stored them in an array. I tried to pass this array but failed. Can anyone help me past this .

P.S: The array thing is just because I couldn't think of anything else.

```
rpt_Uni uniRpt = new rpt_Uni();  
uniRpt.SetDataSource(UniDS.Tables["Uni"]);

if (cmb_Report.SelectedIndex == 0)
{ uniRpt.SetParameterValue("UniParam", txt_UniName.Text); }
else
{ 
    uniRpt.SetParameterValue("UniParameter", ""); 
}

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = uniRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Are the all values a static list?  You could hard-code it if so.

Comment: Are you trying to display the values that were chosen for the parameter or all of its available values?

Comment: All available values if the text box is empty.  BUT 
if there is something in the textbox; that is to be used as the parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your entire parameter values list (or it is static and won't change), you can do something like this:

```
StringVar ParameterList;
If IsNull({?InputParameter}) then
  // to-do assemble your entire list into one string: ThatString
  ParameterList := ThatString;
else
  ParameterList := ToText({?InputParameter});
```